# Starting multiple instances of a binary application using Shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a binary application which when started should technically never terminate and should keep on executing. I want to start multiple instances of this application using a shell script such that the script launches the application specified number of times.

The following script is trying to start multiple such instances, but I am not able to see multiple instances of my program (I saw that the script started only one instance and that too in the same console window)

```
for ((i=1;i<=$instances;i++))
do
./my_program $param1 $param2 $param3 &
done
```

How will I be able to see multiple instances running or is it that multiple instances are running in the background ?

Comment: check with `pgrep -fl my_program`

Comment: man jobs should give you more details

Comment: run `top` or get an overview with `pstree`

Comment: The given script is correct; if thereafter not `$instances` instances of `my_program` are running, it must be because all but one instances have terminated immediately, so it's `my_program`'s fault, and you'd have to show its code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the screen utility to accomplish your objective? It's great for managing as many unattended sessions of whatever you want. http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html